# Nginx equivalent for apache mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ubuntu, centos, ngx-http-rewrite-module

My script is hosted on centos 7 apache server, with below htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now we have migrated the script to a ubuntu 20 server, with nginx webservice. The nginx conf has the following settings:

```
rewrite ^/(.*.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
index index.php index.html;
```

However this does not work for my script.

How can I rewrite this htaccess information for nginx conf instead?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please add details about "it does not work". What is the request you are making? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: Have you solved? I'm interested on how